# why highcharts is giving different results with similar data structure?

Tags: highcharts, yii

I am using highcharts in my yii based application.

after querying the database I am storing the result in a associative array named $catexp
after printing the structure using print_r($catexp) I am getting follwing

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Food [y] => 91 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Utilities [y] => 9 ) )
```

now this the structure of data which can be passed to highchart for generating pie chart.

but after passing this $catexp as data for pie chart I am getting wired output i.e. i am not getting the full chart

although i made a similar manual array structure like this

```
$a = array('name'=> 'Opera','y'=>91);
    $b = array('name'=> 'Safari','y'=>9);
    $c = array($a,$b);
```

print_r($c) gives

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Opera [y] => 91 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Safari [y] => 9 ) )
```

and passed this variable as data for pie chart and i got the full chart.

So my question is what is wrong with my previous chart both the array structures are same but output is diff?????

Comment: Are you sure the generated javascript is identical in these cases? Can you update the question so it contains the javascript as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I found the bug it is basically the y value of $catexp is string and highchart needs number data to draw chart.

So i iterated through the $catexp and converted all y value to double now it is working fine.